# Why isn't this domain giving me results?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

So I'm making this localization kind of module for Lebanon and am currently doing the location bit.
The intended functionality is to have the choices of governate, district and region restrict the choices the user can make by filtering out the irrelevant options.

Here are the models:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api


# Base model
class LebaneseLocation(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    governate_id = fields.Many2one("lebanon.governate", "Governate")
    district_id = fields.Many2one("lebanon.district", "District")
    region_id = fields.Many2one("lebanon.region", "Region")


# Child models with the necessary relations
class Governate(models.Model):
    _name = "lebanon.governate"
    name = fields.Char()
    child_districts = fields.One2many("lebanon.district", "parent_governate",
            "Child Districts")

class District(models.Model):
    _name = "lebanon.district"
    name = fields.Char()
    parent_governate = fields.Many2one("lebanon.governate", "Parent Governate")
    child_regions = fields.One2many("lebanon.region", "parent_district",
            "Child Regions")

class Region(models.Model):
    _name = "lebanon.region"
    name = fields.Char()
    parent_district = fields.Many2one("lebanon.district", "Parent District")
```

and the view file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                  
<odoo>                                                 
    <record id="view_res_partner_extended_location" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Contacts Custom</field>     
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>        
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">                 
            <field name="category_id" position="after">                                                                
                <field name="governate_id" domain="[('child_districts','=?','district_id'),('child_districts.child_regions','=?','region_id')]"/>
                <field name="district_id"/>            
                <field name="region_id"/>              
            </field>                                   
        </field>                                       
    </record>                                          
</odoo>
```

And all the data was inputed via two data files, one makes the records without relations and the other updates the same records with relations.

I was testing things out with the Governate domain and it just kept returning nothing.

Is there some way to check what exactly these parameters i'm evaluating are returning? That would help a lot with debugging.

Edit: Here's a screenshot from Studio's menu for the domain, in case that's at all relevant for debugging (I avoid Studio like a plague usually)
[Domain Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HMdf.png)

Comment: There is some code missing

Comment: @CZoellner Whoops! Fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by forgoing the XML approach and setting the domains using the onchange api call:

```
@api.onchange('governate_id', 'district_id', 'region_id')
def update_domains(self):
    governate = self.governate_id.name
    district = self.district_id.name
    region = self.region_id.name
    result = {}
    result['domain']={
            'governate_id':[('child_districts.name','=?', governate),
                ('child_districts.child_regions.name', '=?', region)],
            'district_id':[('parent_governate.name', '=?', governate),
                ('child_regions.name', '=?', region)],
            'region_id':[('parent_district.name', '=?', district),
                ('parent_district.parent_governate.name', '=?', governate)]
            }
    return result
```